# Find std::function by string key in unordered_map

Tags: c++, collections

This works:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> m = {};
auto c = m.find(typeName);
if (c == m.end())
{

}
```

This works:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> m = {};
auto c = m.find(typeName);
if (c == m.end())
{

}
```

This doesn't work:

```cpp
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void>> m = {};
auto c = m.find(typeName);
if (c == m.end())
{

}
```

`==` shown as error:

In template: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::function' error occurred here (declaration of `_T2 second` inside  inside `pair`)

in instantiation of template class 'std::pair<const std::string, std::function>' requested here

in instantiation of template class 'std::__hash_value_type<std::string, std::function>' requested here template is declared here

P.S. is there any other way storing std::function by string key if there is no way making it work?

Comment: Oh s.. thanks a lot) Can you post it as answer?

Comment: @songyuanyao its intersting that I didn't have any errors declaring such map

Comment: [Gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/UdvVrwsn5MNcmFHN) gives compile-errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) expects a function type as template argument, while `void` is not. For example if the function takes nothing and returns `void` then it should be

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<void()>> m = {};
```